# Can an implementation of an enum that is a Function be expressed using a lambda?

Tags: java, enums, lambda, java-8

Suppose I want to create a set of related functions and want to group them in an enum.

I can code, just for example:

```
enum Case implements Function<Object, String> {
    UPPER {
        public String apply(Object o) {
            return o.toString().toUpperCase();
        }
    },
    LOWER {
        public String apply(Object o) {
            return o.toString().toLowerCase();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to code this as a lambda, something like (but doesn't compile):

```
enum CaseLambda implements Function<Object, String> {
    UPPER (o -> o.toString().toUpperCase()),
    LOWER (o -> o.toString().toLowerCase())
}
```

I've tried a few variations of brackets etc, but nothing compiles.

**Is there a syntax that allows the declaration of enum instance implementation as lambda?**

Comment: I'm curious what the compilation error is.

Comment: Would it work for you to declare a `Function<Object, String>` field in the enum, pass it into the constructor, and call the constructors as in your second snippet? Or is that too much boilerplate?

Comment: @yshavit That is what I assumed he was trying to do in the 2nd snippet. (Maybe my assumption was wrong though.)

Comment: There's not nearly as much _point_ to wrapping your `Function`s in enums in Java 8.  The implementation is smart enough to extract a singleton lambda, rather than regenerating it each time it's referenced, so you might as well just insert the lambdas directly into the places you use them.

Comment: @LouisWasserman but I want the benefits of using an enum to show the developer the list of functions that make sense (ie strongly type a set of supported functionality), and I'm also iterating over them and applying all functions in a particular case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, the [`enum` constant syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1) does not allow it. If you declare a constant with a body, that body is a [`classbody`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassBody).

[yshavit's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665662/can-an-implementation-of-an-enum-that-is-a-function-be-expressed-using-a-lambda/26665697#comment41933167_26665662) seems appropriate. Delegate to the `Function` implementation.

```
enum Case implements Function<Object, String> {
    UPPER (o -> o.toString().toUpperCase()),
    LOWER (o -> o.toString().toLowerCase());

    private final Function<Object, String> func;

    private Case(Function<Object, String> func) {
        this.func = func;
    }

    @Override
    public String apply(Object t) {
        return func.apply(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Close enough - I'll take it as a win! Not too much boiler plate, because at least it doesn't repeat the boilerplate. If there are many instances, the brevity will be welcome.

Comment: Note that some aspects of this pattern have been already discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23361418/2711488)…