# java enum including a function - use switch or supplier as member variable

Tags: java, lambda, enums, java-8, switch-statement

I want to have an enum that provides a function that includes a constructor of a new class. Before Java8 I used to write this code:

```
enum Fruit1 {
    APPLE, BANANA;

    public Tree getTree() {
        switch (this) {
            case APPLE:
                return new AppleTree();
            case BANANA:
                return new BananaTree();
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can use lambda expressions. The advantage is, when adding a new enum entry, you cannot forget adding sth to the switch statement. But I dont like that the code looks more complicated to me.

```
enum Fruit2 {
    APPLE(AppleTree::new), BANANA(BananaTree::new);

    Supplier<Tree> treeSupplier;

    Fruit2(Supplier<Tree> treeSupplier) {
        this.treeSupplier = treeSupplier;
    }

    public Tree getTree() {
        return treeSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

Is it just a matter of taste or is there more to it? Can I do it in a nicer way using lambda expressions?

This is strongly related to [other questions comparing lambda expressions to abstract methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277562/is-there-any-reason-to-override-methods-in-enums-in-java-8), but here I would like to focus on the switch expression, that I am still quite comfortable with (in comparison to lambda expressions).

Comment: If the code looks more complicated to you, why would you want to use it? I find it simpler and nicer. But define what you consider nicer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any reason to override methods in enums in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277562/is-there-any-reason-to-override-methods-in-enums-in-java-8)

Comment: The lambda expression variant is free of conditionals, but of course, a hotspot optimizer should be able to optimize the `switch` statement variant to a similar outcome, if it ever becomes performance relevant. Then, the only difference is the necessity of writing `default: throw new IllegalStateException();` in the `switch` statement to make the compiler happy. The lambda variant does not need that…

Answer (score 4):

Your second snippet looks fine. If you feel otherwise, you can do something similar by bringing the implementation of your method at the enum constant level:

```
enum Fruit1 {
  APPLE {
    public Tree getTree() { return new AppleTree(); }
  }, BANANA {
    public Tree getTree() { return new BananaTree(); }
 };

  public abstract Tree getTree();
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution -- I've found that often using functions rather than functional types gives you the option of doing either.  With this solution, if you still needed a supplier you could create one using method references, like `myFruit::getTree` or `APPLE::getTree`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should ask yourself is whether it is a good idea to have such a tight coupling between the `Fruit` enumeration and the `Tree` class hierarchy at all. Consider the alternative:

```
public enum Fruit { APPLE, BANANA }

public class TreeFactory {
    static EnumMap<Fruit,Supplier<Tree>> SUPPLIERS=new EnumMap<>(Fruit.class);
    static {
        SUPPLIERS.put(Fruit.APPLE,  AppleTree::new);
        SUPPLIERS.put(Fruit.BANANA, BananaTree::new);
        assert SUPPLIERS.keySet().containsAll(EnumSet.allOf(Fruit.class));
    }
    public static Tree getTree(Fruit f) {
        return SUPPLIERS.getOrDefault(
            Objects.requireNonNull(f), ()->{throw new AssertionError();}).get();
    }
}
```

The `enum` specialized collections are efficient as the hard-coded alternatives, like the `switch` statement or storing data in the `enum` constants themselves. But this solution works without the need for the `Fruit` type to know anything about the `Tree` types.

Comment: Great thanks a lot, I like the decoupling of fruit and tree as well as the assert check for suppliers.