# Annotation to support refactoring of a functional interface

Tags: java, refactoring, implements, automated-refactoring, functional-interface

Consider the following example:

```
public interface Greeter {
    String greet();
}

public class ExplicitGreeterImpl implements Greeter {
    @Override
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

public class ImplicitGreeterImpl {
    public String doTheGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

private void run() {
    System.out.println(new ExplicitGreeterImpl().greet());

    Greeter foo = new ImplicitGreeterImpl()::doTheGreeting;
    System.out.println(foo.greet());
}
```

The functional interface `Greeter` has two implementations. `ExplicitGreeterImpl` implements `Greeter` using the `implements` clause, while `ImplicitGreeterImpl::doTheGreeting` implements `Greeter` without it. Nevertheless, `ImplicitGreeterImpl::doTheGreeting` is designed to implement `Greeter`, just like `ExplicitGreeterImpl`.

Now, I want to refactor the `Greeter` interface, so I can pass a name to it:

```
public interface Greeter {
    String greet(String name);
}
```

I can do this with the *Change Method Signature* refactoring provided by Eclipse (I am sure other IDEs have a similar refactoring). This automatically updates all implementations and usages of the `Greeter` interface. Implementations receive the new parameter, while usages pass a configurable default value. This works fine for the `ExplicitGreeterImpl`, however the refactoring does not touch the `ImplicitGreeterImpl::doTheGreeting` method. Thus, the assignment

```
Greeter foo = new ImplicitGreeterImpl()::doTheGreeting;
```

becomes a compile-time error. To fix this, I have to manually adjust the signature of the method `ImplicitGreeterImpl::doTheGreeting`.

Now, I understand that it is undesirable in many cases to automatically adjust the signature of `ImplicitGreeterImpl::doTheGreeting`. However, I feel that the current workflow can be improved:

- Eclipse does not display a warning in the refactoring preview that suggests that there will be a compile-time error.
- It should be possible to annotate the method to clarify that it is supposed to implement a given functional interface.

For example, `ImplicitGreeterImpl` could look like this:

```
public class ImplicitGreeterImpl {
    @Implements(Greeter.class)
    public String doTheGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Now, refactoring tools could be sure that `ImplicitGreeterImpl::doTheGreeting` is supposed to implement `Greeter` and thus, they can automatically change its signature.

Thus, my question is: Is there a way to tell refactoring tools that a given method is supposed to implement a given functional interface? I searched for the annotation proposed above, but I did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept searching for an answer, but there does not seem to be a solution that uses an annotation. However, when asking the question I had a specific use case in mind: I want to write down many different implementations of the same functional interface in a single file. Indeed, there is a solution for this problem, which also works great with automatic refactoring tools:

```
public interface Greeter {
    String greet();
}

public enum EnumGreeterImpl implements Greeter {
    GREETER1 {
        @Override
        public String greet() {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    },
    GREETER2 {
        @Override
        public String greet() {
            return "Foo bar";
        }
    },
}

private void run() {
    Greeter foo = EnumGreeterImpl.GREETER1;
    System.out.println(foo.greet());
}
```

See also:

- [How to ensure at Java 8 compile time that a method signature “implements” a functional interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30196934/3888450)
- [Lambdas in the classical Operation enum example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23361418/3888450)

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you need to implement the interface.
If you can add an annotation linking to the interface, why not make your class implement it?

Comment: There is actually a good reason to not implement the interface directly, but to use the method reference. Consider the command pattern. In this case: (1) The Command interface is probably a functional interface, (2) there are many implementations of the Command interface and (3) each of these implementations is very simple. Adding an extra class for each of these implementations adds a lot of noise to the code. However, if each Command implementation is just a method, the code becomes much cleaner.