# Shorthand notation for Enum implementing lambda possible interface

Tags: java, lambda, enums, java-8, enumeration

Coming across an pre-Java 8 example from jparsec, I wondered if I could leverage lambdas for a more expressive syntax.

Original example:

```
enum BinaryOperator implements Map2<Double,Double,Double> {
  PLUS {
    public Double map(Double a, Double b) {
      return a + b;
    }
  },
  MINUS {
    public Double map(Double a, Double b) {
      return a - b;
    }
  },
  MUL {
    public Double map(Double a, Double b) {
      return a * b;
    }
  },
  DIV {
    public Double map(Double a, Double b) {
      return a / b;
    }
  }
}
```

where

```
public interface Map2<A, B, T> {

  /** Maps {@code a} and {@code b} to the target object. */
  T map(A a, B b);
}
```

**A plain Map2 instance is easily created with e.g. `(a,b)->a+b`, but is there a concise way to do the same for enums implementing a single function interface?**

My current solution looks like this, but it is still verbose:

```
enum BinaryOperator implements Map2<Double,Double,Double> {
    PLUS((a, b) -> a + b), MINUS((a, b) -> a - b), MUL((a, b) -> a * b), DIV((a, b) -> a / b);

    private final BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> f;

    private BinaryOperator(BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    @Override
    public Double map(Double a, Double b) {
        return f.apply(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can get much better than your current solution. Differences between enum constants can only be expressed in two ways: implementing a method or passing a constructor argument. The first one is the one we want to move away from, so constructor argument is our only choice. The constructor argument must be placed in a field. The enum must also implement `map()`, and we've arrived to your solution.

Comment: I see eight lines of constant boilerplate code and the amount of code per constant as short as, e.g. `PLUS((a, b) -> a + b),`. How much more concise do you want to get? Related: [“Lambdas in the classical Operation enum example”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23361418/2711488)

Answer (score 7):

The appropriate interface would be [`DoubleBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleBinaryOperator.html) here. This interface is suited when you need to operate on two `double` values and return a `double`. It works on primitive `double` instead of the wrapper class, thereby it doesn't have boxing overhead.

Your current solution is still the way to go. The code is clearly factored and there's no duplication. With the above interface, you can have:

```
enum BinaryOperator implements DoubleBinaryOperator {
    PLUS((a, b) -> a + b),
    MINUS((a, b) -> a - b),
    MUL((a, b) -> a * b),
    DIV((a, b) -> a / b);

    private final DoubleBinaryOperator f;

    private BinaryOperator(DoubleBinaryOperator f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    @Override
    public double applyAsDouble(double a, double b) {
        return f.applyAsDouble(a, b);
    }

}
```

Implementing the `DoubleBinaryOperator` interface can prove to be useful: this way you can use the enum values directly as `DoubleBinaryOperator`, like:

```
DoubleStream.of(1, 2, 3).reduce(0, BinaryOperator.PLUS);
```

(This is just an example; there are better ways to do this specific instance.)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, much more concise would be to use an `EnumMap` that maps every single `Operation` value to its corresponding operation:

```
enum Operator { PLUS, MINUS, MUL, DIV; }
```

Then, you would need to initialize the `EnumMap`:

```
EnumMap<Operator, DoubleBinaryOperator> operations = new EnumMap<>(Operator.class);
operations.put(Operator.PLUS, (a, b) -> a + b);
operations.put(Operator.MINUS, (a, b) -> a - b);
operations.put(Operator.MUL, (a, b) -> a * b);
operations.put(Operator.DIV, (a, b) -> a / b);
```

Usage example:

```
double result = operations.get(Operator.MUL).applyAsDouble(2.0, 3.0); // 6.0
```

---

**EDIT:** As @Holger suggests in the comments, it would be nice to check that you've added all possible enum values to the map. That could be accomplished with an `assert`:

```
assert operations.keySet().equals(EnumSet.allOf(Operator.class));
```

Comment: The problem is, you don’t notice if you forget to put a particular key into the map. Ok, adding a statement like `assert operations.keySet().equals(EnumSet.allOf(Operator.class));` after the initialization can solve this.

Comment: @Holger I'll add your recommendation to my answer. Thanks!